# i am having problems launching juypter on windows, it keeps showing a notepod

Tags: python, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda environment on my windows after which I tried launching Jupyter notebook in the anaconda environment instead of launching via my browser, it kept taking me to my windows notepad [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0r6z.jpg)

Comment: So you are clicking on the "launch" button in the Anaconda Navigator and then your notepad opens?

Comment: Please you have to gives us more clue about your installation

Comment: No, after installing the Anaconda Navigator , it opened quite well but on trying to launch jupyter notebook, my notepad pops up instead of Jupyter notebook showing my files ,but I did find a solution, I was told to go change my program default which before enables .html to be opened by notepod instead of my browser. I hope this is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that the jupyter kernel is started and then it tries to launch an `.html` file with the typical jupyter landing page. However, it seems that `.html` files seem to be associated with your `notepad` and not with a browser on your system. You can now do two things:

1. Notice how there is a link in the opened document, something with `localhost:8888` and so on, this is the link to your running jupyter instance, just copy paste it into your browser
2. For a more long term solution, you should change the association of `.html` files to be opened by your favourite browser. To do this, either follow the instructions on this site: [change-file-associations-windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows). Or you create a new file, change the extension to `.html` and then choose `open with->choose another app` in the right click menu, select your browser and tick the "always use this app to open `.html` files" checkbox

Comment: I'm so grateful...you saved a life lol